# How can I make the function work with the updated state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a handleValid function to validate a form, and when I click submit, the function is triggered for validation and calls handleSelfValidation, in the handleSelfValidation app they write the form state information and change the state, but handleInfoCheck is looking at the previous state, and for this reason I need to click twice to "Send".

```
const handleValid = () => {
    members
      .filter((member: Tourist) => {
        return member.createdIn === touristCreatedIn && !member.isEmployee;
      })
      .forEach((member: any, index: any) => {
        personSchema
          .validate(member, { abortEarly: false })
          .then(() => {
            setFieldError({
              [index]: {}
            })
          })
          .catch((errs: any) => {
            setFieldError({})
            errs?.inner?.forEach((err: any) => {
              setFieldError((prev)=> ({
                ...prev,
                [index]: {
                  ...prev[index],
                  [err.path]: err.message,
                },
              }))
            });
          });

        personSchema
          .isValid(member)
          .then((v: any) => {
            console.log('тут', v, index)
            handleSelfValidation(v, index); //isFormValid - true
          })
          .catch((err: any) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.error('TouristData YUP isValid Err', err);
          });
      });
    setTimeout(handleInfoCheck);
  };

const handleSelfValidation = (isFormValid: boolean, formIndex: number) => {
    console.log(isFormValid, formIndex, 'test')
    setIsFormsValid((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [formIndex]: isFormValid,
    }))
  };

const handleInfoCheck = () => {
    setFirstVisit();

    if (
      Object.values(isFormsValid).every((item: any) => {
        return item === true;
      })
    ) {
      switch (permissionType) {
        case 'tour':
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tour-data`);
          break;
        case PERMISSION_TYPE_TRANZIT:
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tranzit-data`);
          break;
        default:
          history.push(`${addTourUrl}/tour-data`);
          break;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: You can wrap the handleSelfValidation function inside a useCallback and give the changing state variables as dependencies.

Comment: Doest't work ,
const handleSelfValidation = useCallback((isFormValid: boolean, formIndex: number) => {
    console.log(isFormValid, formIndex, 'test')
    setIsFormsValid((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [formIndex]: isFormValid,
    }))
  }, [isFormsValid]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that React state updates are asynchronously processed, and the state from the current render cycle is closed over in `handleValid`/`handleInfoCheck` callback scope.

## Solution

Allow the `isFormsValid` state update to occur in `handleSelfValidation` and use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `isFormsValid` to run the additional code.

```
const handleValid = () => {
  members
    .filter((member: Tourist) => {
      return member.createdIn === touristCreatedIn && !member.isEmployee;
    })
    .forEach((member: any, index: any) => {
      ...

      personSchema
        .isValid(member)
        .then((v: any) => {
          console.log('тут', v, index)
          handleSelfValidation(v, index); // <-- updates state
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error('TouristData YUP isValid Err', err);
        });
    });
};

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFormsValid) {
    handleInfoCheck();
  }
}, [handleInfoCheck, isFormsValid]);
```